# sbt dependency resolving failed

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I am using sbt in one of the scala project. However, it keep failing at resolving 
scala-xml_2.11_1.04. Though I can access the pom using my browser.

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:<br/>...<br/><pre>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.4/sc…
```

> [trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last
>   capstoneUI/*:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output. [trace] Stack
>   trace suppressed: run 'last capstoneUI/*:coursierResolution' for the
>   full output. [error] (capstoneUI/*:ssExtractDependencies)
>   coursier.ResolutionException: Encountered 1 error(s) in dependency
>   resolution: [error]   org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:1.0.4:
>   [error]     download error: Caught java.io.IOException: Server
>   returned HTTP response code: 416 for URL:
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/modules/scala-xml_2.11/1.0.4/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.4.pom
>   [error]     not found: [error]
>   C:\Users\caixi.ivy2\local\org.scala-lang.modules\scala-xml_2.11\1.0.4\ivys\ivy.xml
>
> [error] Total time: 7 s, completed Jul 17, 2017 10:47:57 AM

Comment: I managed to resolve this problem by adding the dependencies of scalatic and scalatest to all the subproject sbt and root build.sbt<br>

Comment: I managed to resolve this problem by adding the dependencies of scalatic and scalatest to all the subproject sbt and root build.sbt  `"org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.1" `  and  `"org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.1" % "test"`